# How To Create Map View without XAML in ArcGIS Runtime for .NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have three projects here. There are Client, Server, and UserControl which contains with ArcGIS. Let me call the UserControl as UserControl map. I use the UserControl in the client. To synchronize between client and server, I created libraries which contain functions of calculating map, such as the function of GetMapPosition, GetMapDepth, etc. In the GetMapPosition, I need to use the function of ScreenToLocation. For access it, I must create the map view in my libraries class. That's why I must create the map view without XAML. Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: This is a cross post of the following: https://geonet.esri.com/message/688228-how-to-create-map-view-without-xaml-in-arcgis-runtime-for-net